# Why is the image always faded when it is inserted to sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

When I try to insert images to my sketch app, they're faded in white.
I have googled but couldn't find the answer.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it's possible that some setting gets automatically applied... It does sort of look like some sort of error or blend more or something... You may have to contact Sketch app support.